# Is it considered natural to open an answer with 'On the contrary!'?

Tags: phrases

> *Person A*: He says that you like sweet foods.
>
> *Person B*: **[On the contrary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-contrary)!** I do like salty foods.

Is it considered natural to open an answer or comment with this phrase, or it should be a part of a previous sentence?

Comment: Your example has an exclamation mark at the end of it. That means that Person B has uttered two sentences. What you mean when you ask if it should be part of a "previous sentence"? It's its own sentence …

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But this is exactly my question:) I built this example with person A&B and I'd like to know if it is considered natural to speak that way. As I understand from your note it's absolutely natural. Isn't it?

Comment: My problem with this, is that liking salty foods is not contrary to liking sweet foods. If Person A said '*He says that you **only** like sweet food*', then person B could legitimately say something like '*On the contrary! I like savoury food even more*' as that would be contrary to the original statement.

Comment: *On the contrary!* is an entirely common response to somebody who says something the opposite of what's believed. I agree with the previous comment too. In this example, *On the contrary!* would imply they ***don't*** like sweet foods—not that they like salty foods.

Answer (score -1):

> Person A: He says that you like sweet foods.
>   Person B: **On the contrary**, I like salty foods. (you don't need the "do" here)

It's quite natural to do that, in my opinion, though it's not super common. Usually, you would have a sentence before "On the contrary" to contradict, but in spoken English, you can use the other person's sentence(s) as your sentence-to-contradict. Note that you need a comma after "On the contrary".

You can, without the comma but a new sentence instead, say this:

> **Quite the contrary**! I like salty foods.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this answer without any explanation.